# Python Machine Learning - how to get the prediction speed of a model?

Tags: python, performance, machine-learning, scikit-learn, prediction

I am trying to measure the prediction speed (in seconds) of my python machine learning model. I can't find a good answer for this yet. Can you guys help me? this is my example code:

```
# Create Decision Tree classifer object
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy", max_depth=3)

# Train Decision Tree Classifer
clf = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

#Predict the response for test dataset. I want to measure the speed of this prediction here.
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to time it! Use timestamps before and after the inference and take the difference.

```py
import time

#get the timestamp before inference in seconds
start_ts = time.time()

#Predict the response for test dataset. I want to measure the speed of this prediction here.
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

#get the timestamp after the inference in second
end_ts = time.time()

# print the time difference in between start and end timestamps in seconds
print(f"Prediction Time [s]: {(end_ts-start_ts):.3f}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I use below code to measure time taken:

```
from time import time 

ti = time()
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
print('Time taken: {:.1f} sec'.format(time() - ti))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save a timestamp before running your prediction code and one after. The duration is then the difference between timestamps. Note the use of `time.perf_counter_ns()`, which returns monotonic time that only increases. In contrast to `time.time()`, which can also decrease when for example the system clock is synchronised with an external server.

```py
from time import perf_counter_ns

# Start time stamp
t_start = perf_counter_ns() 

# Predict the response for the test dataset
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

# Stop time stamp
t_stop = perf_counter_ns()

# The difference between both time stamps is the duration
duration = t_stop - t_start

print("Elapsed time: {1000 * duration:.2f} ms")
```

See also [PEP 418 – Add monotonic time, performance counter, and process time functions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0418/).